# Computing the matrix of rotation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups

Let $\gamma_P$ denote the conjugation by $P\in SU_2$. Let $P=(\cos\theta)I+(\sin\theta)A$ where $A$ is on the equator. I want to know how I compute $\gamma_P$. I know it's defined by conjugation $PBP^*$, but what is $B$?

Comment: $\gamma_P$, defined as "conjugation by $P \in SU(2)$," simply turns a matrix $B$ into $PBP^{-1}$, that is, $\gamma_P(B) = PBP^{-1}$. So, as $\gamma_P$ currently defined, $B$ could be any $2\times 2$ matrix whatsoever, and $\gamma_P(B)$ would be a linear transformation. I'm afraid I don't know what is meant by $A$ *is on the equator*.

Comment: The exact phrasing is this. Suppose that $P=(\cos\theta)I+(\sin\theta)A$ with $0<\theta<\pi$ and $A$ on the equator (this means that $\text{trace}A=0$, i.e. $A=x_1\mathbf{i}+x_2\mathbf{j}+x_3\mathbf{k}$ ($x_0=0$ in $S^3$)). Compute the matrix of the rotation $\gamma_P$, and show that its trace is $1+2\cos\theta$.

Comment: Given the context, my bet is that $\gamma_P$ should be consider as an automorphism of the corresponding Lie Algebra

Answer (score 0):

Given the context, I assume that we're supposed to consider 
$\gamma_P:\mathfrak{su}_2 \to \mathfrak{su}_2$, where $\mathfrak{su}_2$ denotes the Lie algebra corresponding to $SU_2$, consisting of the traceless skew-Hermitian matrices.

Let $u_1,u_2,u_3$ denote the basis for $SU_2$ given by the Pauli matrices, as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group#n_.3D_2).  That is, we take
$$
u_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & i\\
i & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad
u_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad
u_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
i & 0\\
0 & -i
\end{pmatrix}
$$
now, compute the matrix of the linear transformation $\gamma_P$ relative to this basis.